# How does C call functions without parameters?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am learning C by [building my own Lisp](http://buildyourownlisp.com/chapter11_variables) and I'm having trouble figuring out how the next line of code works:

```
lenv_add_builtin(e, "def", builtin_def);
```

What I don't understand is: how does the third parameter call a function without parameters `(lenv*, lval*)`. My guess is they are built as `typedef structs` but I am not sure. 
Here is the entire code

```
// function pointer
typedef lval*(*lbuiltin)(lenv*, lval*);

lval* builtin_def(lenv* e, lval* a){
    return lval_sexpr(); 
}

void lenv_add_builtins(lenv* e){
    lenv_add_builtin(e, "def", builtin_def); // ???
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    lenv* e = lenv_new(); // constructor
    lenv_add_builtins(e)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function pointer: the function is not being called, but just passed.

Comment: The third argument isn't a function call; it is a function pointer.  The function pointed at will be called later.

Comment: `lenv_add_builtin` would create the proper two paramters. When `lenv_add_builtin` gets called and gets passed `builtin_def` its just a memory location to the function, passing it in like that doesn't mean its being called immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line

```
lenv_add_builtin(e, "def", builtin_def);
```

does not call `builtin_def`. It is used as pointer (to a function) in the call to `lenv_add_builtin`.

Comment: Ok I see, so any function without parameters is used as pointer (to a function)? Or should I have to declare it like this `lenv* (*builtin_def)(int, int)` to make it possible.

Or as @Jens says in the answer below, that a function identifier not followed by () evaluates as a function pointer

Comment: @Pompeyo, Yes. You still have to declare it. Otherwise, the compiler won't know type of the variable. What Jens said is true.

Answer (score 2):

The C language specifies that a function identifier not followed by the function call operator `()` evaluates to the address of the function (aka *function pointer*).

The typical use for function pointers is to serve as callbacks. The standard example is the `qsort` function's last argument, which is the address of an arbitrary comparison function.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't calling a function; it is passing a function (technically, a function pointer) that can be USED to call that function, at which point the needed parameters will be provided.